# Spec not failing on Mockito Matchers.any[FooException] matcher

Tags: scala, specs2

In my spec, I expect the mock invocation `msg.ctx.failWith(any[TimeoutException])`.

Because `failWith` takes a `Throwable`, the type of the exception is not checked - even at runtime.

This nonsense passes:

```
there was one(msg.ctx).failWith(Matchers.any[ArrayIndexOfOutBoundsException])
```

Can I assert that the correct type of exception is passed?

I'm using Specs 2.3.13 (because it is a dependency of akka-test-kit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not pretty but it works:

```
there was one(m).failWith(beLike[Throwable] { case _: TimeoutException => ok })
```

Comment: Nice stuff Eric. How many times have you saved my bacon now? You're a legend.

Comment: I'm happy when I can help :-)